# What's the difference between the sender and the from field in Net::IMAP::Envelope?

Tags: ruby, imap

If you look at the doc for Net::IMAP::Envelope here

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/classes/Net/IMAP.html

the struct includes these two fields:

```
from:   Returns an array of Net::IMAP::Address that represents the from.
sender: Returns an array of Net::IMAP::Address that represents the sender.
```

What's the difference between these two fields, conceptually?

Comment: In email there's also `Reply-To:` thrown into the mix of addresses who you could reply to in a message response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing fields that IMAP parsed from the email message itself. From [Wikipedia's Email: Header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reply-To#Header_fields):

> From: The email address, and optionally the name of the author(s). In many email clients not changeable except through changing account settings.
>
> Sender: Address of the actual sender acting on behalf of the author listed in the From: field (secretary, list manager, etc.).

There's also Reply-To which has to be considered when you want to reply to a message:

> Reply-To: Address that should be used to reply to the message.

There is a bit more discussion on that page about spoofing and attempts by the MTA (server) to avoid and detect it, but the above is the gist of the info.